# setContentView is unidentified

Tags: android, setcontentview

The `setContentView` is underscored with red squiggle. I cleaned the workspace but the same error remains. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
public class SensorsTest01 extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_tab_bar);
}
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setContentView() should not be used instead we have to create a view in onCreateView() of the Fragment Method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail,
        container, false);
    return view;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`setContentView()` is a method defined in `Activity`.

Looks like you need `extends Activity` instead of `extends Fragment`.

Comment: but i want to use a fragment! is not that possible?

Comment: The code you posted is not typical fragment code. If you want a fragment, you're welcome to write one but you don't need `setContentView()` there.

Comment: Actually, i am following a tutorial, and at the beginning as the tutorial suggested i should have used TabActivity but i found it is deprecated and eclipse suggested to use Fragment

Comment: can you please see this tutorial:http://androidexample.com/Tab_Layout_|_TabBar_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=103&aaid=125

Comment: That tutorial, as you can see yourself, uses Activities, not Fragments... Activities and Fragments are different beasts.

Comment: @Elpharaoh : If you want to use a tutorial then don't trust everything you see on the Internet. Follow the official Google / Android tutorials instead.